# Sound comes from speakers only when headphones are plugged

Tags: sound, headphones, soundcard

I have the weirdest behaviour on my new laptop (Huawei matebook 16s). After installing Kubuntu 22.04 the sound card got recognized.

The weird behaviour is, when I play anything, no sound comes out of the speaker of the laptop. When I plug the headphones, the sound starts coming out of the laptop speakers, but no sound comes out of the headphones. Once I unplug the headphones, sound stops coming out of the laptop speakers. I cannot manage to get any sound out of the headphones.

I reinstalled Windows to check, everything works fine there, normal behaviour.

I tried to follow some troubleshooting but nothing worked. I got some info about the card using an ALSA script.

Manufacturer: HUAWEI
Product Name: CREFG-XX
Product Version: M1010
Firmware Version: 1.07
System SKU: C233
Board Vendor: HUAWEI
Board Name: CREFG-XX-PCB

I don’t know what to do next. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did try to tweak the settings under `gnome-control-center` → **Sound**?